# Uncaught TypeError: lab.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I can't figure out why `JQuery` says that lab.find() is not a function. I'm looking for a text in this html:

```
<div class="btn-group col-md-4" data-toggle="buttons">

    <label data-pk="4" id="languagebuttonselect1" class="btn prmr-btn-empty top-margin left-margin center-elements target_language_choice active" style="padding: 8px;  color: black; width: 100%;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="target_languages" value="4" autocomplete="off">

        <img align="left" width="30px" style="margin-bottom: 0;" src="/static/img/flags/550px\gb.png">
        <b class="left-margin" style="text-align: left">English</b>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
```

And I want to get text (in this case "English") when a class of the tag (label) is `active`.

```
function refreshSummaryTaretLanguages(){
    var actives = $('.target_language_choice.active');
    var summ_ul_targ_langs = $('#summary_target_languages > ul');
    summ_ul_targ_langs.empty();

    $.each(actives,function (_,lab) {
        summ_ul_targ_langs.append('<li>'+lab.find('b').text()+'</li>');
    })
}
```

Unfortunately it can't find anything in such tag and I don't know what to do.

Comment: It means that `lab` is something other than a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery passes the `$.each` callback the elements of the array, so you're getting DOM nodes, not jQuery objects.

It would be simpler to just use the `.each()` method on the jQuery object you already have:

```
$(actives).each(function() {
    summ_ul_targ_langs.append('<li>'+$(this).find('b').text()+'</li>');
});
```

The `.each()` callback does basically the same thing as `$.each()`, and will also pass in the element. It also arranges for the callback to be invoked such that `this` references the element too. Wrapping `this` as `$(this)` gives you a jQuery object from which you can call `.find()`.